# Problema session_start

Tags: php

Ayuda. Tengo un problema con el siguiente script php. El error se detacta al subir el script a internet, en el servidor local funciona sin problema.

Me encuentro el siguiente error:

Agradezco la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo php.

```
<?php

class Ingreso{

public function ingresoController(){

    if(isset($_POST["usuarioIngreso"])){

        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["usuarioIngreso"])&&
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["passwordIngreso"])){

            #$encriptar = crypt($_POST["passwordIngreso"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');

            $datosController = array("usuario"=>$_POST["usuarioIngreso"],
                                 "password"=>$_POST["passwordIngreso"]);

            $respuesta = IngresoModels::ingresoModel($datosController, "usuarios");

            $intentos = $respuesta["intentos"];
            $usuarioActual = $_POST["usuarioIngreso"];
            $maximoIntentos = 2;

            if($intentos < $maximoIntentos){

                if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["usuarioIngreso"] && $respuesta["password"] == $_POST["passwordIngreso"]){

                    $intentos = 0;

                    $datosController = array("usuarioActual"=>$usuarioActual, "actualizarIntentos"=>$intentos);

                    $respuestaActualizarIntentos = IngresoModels::intentosModel($datosController, "usuarios");

                    session_start();

                    $_SESSION["validar"] = true;
                    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $respuesta["usuario"];
                    $_SESSION["nombre"] = $respuesta["nombre"];
                    $_SESSION["id_us"] = $respuesta["id_us"];
                    $_SESSION["rol"] = $respuesta["rol"];
                    //$_SESSION["photo"] = $respuesta["photo"];*/
                    // $_SESSION["password"] = $respuesta["password"];
                    // $_SESSION["email"] = $respuesta["email"];


                    header("location:eventos");

                }

                else{

                    ++$intentos;

                    $datosController = array("usuarioActual"=>$usuarioActual, "actualizarIntentos"=>$intentos);

                    $respuestaActualizarIntentos = IngresoModels::intentosModel($datosController, "usuarios");

                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">4 Error al ingresar</div>';

                }

            }

            else{

                    $intentos = 0;

                    $datosController = array("usuarioActual"=>$usuarioActual, "actualizarIntentos"=>$intentos);

                    $respuestaActualizarIntentos = IngresoModels::intentosModel($datosController, "usuarios");

                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Ha fallado 3 veces, demuestre que no es un robot</div>';

            }

        }

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambos errores indican que ya se comenzó a escribir una respuesta cuando tratas de modificar las cabeceras de la petición. Esto se produce tanto con `SESSION_START()` como con `HEADER()`.

Para verificar esto, puedes indicar a php que salga de forma forzada antes de ejecutar `SESSION_START()` con `EXIT`

```
...

$respuestaActualizarIntentos = IngresoModels::intentosModel($datosController, "usuarios");

exit("Antes de este mensaje, no debería aparecer nada en el cuerpo de la respuesta. Si es así, no puedo utilizar session_start ni header en este punto.");

session_start();

$_SESSION["validar"] = true;

...
```